# NLog File archiving

Tags: logging, archive, nlog

Can I accomplish the following using *NLog*:

1. The log files are created in the following format - `LogFileName_YYYY_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss.log`.
2. When the size of the file exceeds a configured size for ex:-  a new log file is created with the same format - `LogFileName_YYYY_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss.log`.

Answer (score 0):

NLog's documentation is pretty good on their website:

[File target - NLog](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target)

Comment: I tried the documentation . when i give the file name in the following formay -LogFileName_YYYY_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss.log , it produces a new log file every second

Comment: I'm going to chance my arm here and say that I don't think what you want to do is possible. When you set a log name with a time stamp in it NLog uses the current time (when trying to write a log entry) to find the appropriate file. If it can't find it, it creates it, hence your new log file every second. There may be a way of setting the log name from within your code, but then you lose the flexibility of setting it within a configuration file.

Comment: I corrected your link. Please don't post link-only answers. Instead of that, try to sumarize the content of the link and use the link as a reference, so if the URL got broken the answer keep being valid.